# How to debug a python module that needs to be executed with -m?

Tags: python, debugging, command-line, relative-import, pudb

Every debugger I tried out there expects a source file to debug. However Python does not always work this way.

I have a module that is a folder with `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` files inside, among others, and I usually execute that this way:

```
$ cd /parent/folder
$ python3 -m module_folder --help
```

If I don't use `-m`, relative imports fail. If I just pass the folder to `pudb`, `pdb` and others, debugger fails:

```
$ cd /parent/folder
$ python3 -m pdb module_folder
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/pdb.py", line 1658, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.3/pdb.py", line 1536, in _runscript
    with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'module_folder'
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
Running 'cont' or 'step' will restart the program
> /usr/lib64/python3.3/pdb.py(1536)_runscript()
-> with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
(Pdb)
```

How can I debug this? Preferrably with `pudb`, and without removing the relative imports.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could find a way to achieve this that doesn't require modifying the program source and doesn't require changing the working directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this at the top of your `__main__.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Declare itself as package if needed
if __name__ == '__main__' and __package__ is None:
    import os, sys, importlib
    parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(parent_dir))
    __package__ = os.path.basename(parent_dir)
    importlib.import_module(__package__)

# Continue with your code
do_things()
```

This way, these 2 commands become equivalent:

1. `cd /parent/folder; python -m module_folder`
2. `python /parent/folder/module_folder/__main__.py`

Just use the 2nd syntax for debugging:

```
pudb /parent/folder/module_folder/__main__.py
```

or

```
python3 -m pdb /parent/folder/module_folder/__main__.py
```

The same works for Python 2.

You can safely remove from the above code the part `__name__ == '__main__' and` because, as you are writing in `__main__.py`, it would always be `True`. However, it's a common practice to put it. See [PEP 366](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/) and [this other answer](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0366/).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
$ cd /parent/folder
$ python3 -m pdb -m module_folder
```

As it was, you were missing the second `-m` which was making Python think that `module_folder` was meant to be the name of a script to run.

Comment: That's what I want to do, but it says `getopt.GetoptError: option -m not recognized`.

Comment: This is a very new feature and only works for python ~ 3.7 or later: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4752

Comment: @user: I don't think so, as I wrote this answer in 2013, when Python 3.7 did not exist.  Or, maybe this answer saw into the future by 5 years?

Comment: It is simple, they saw your answer and copied it. When I tried you answer with CPython 3.6, it threw this error `getopt.GetoptError: option -m not recognized`. But when I updagraded to Python 3.7.2, it worked fine.